# Mutate with case_when long format dataset dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a dataset that all medical consultation is gathered. Since I have some time interval, I'll have measure 1,2,...,n.

Now I want to compare the results obtained at the first measurement point (the baseline) with the next results. If the second, third, fourth (etc) measurement difference is lesser than 0.5, this outcome is ok; but if no difference is present, the outcome is not ok.

That's a straightforward action when we have the dataset in the wide format, but I'm working with long format within dplyr framework.

My dataset looks like this one:

[image: dataset]

I think something in this direction could be ok, but I've got some error messages..

```
ds <- ds %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    improvement = 
      case_when(result[time != "Baseline"] - result[time == "Baseline"] <= 0.5 ~ 1)
  )
```

To reproduce the analyses:

```
ds <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
                              4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6), group = c("AG", "AG", "AG", 
                                                                         "AG", "AG", "AG", "AG", "AG", "AG", "BG", "BG", "BG", "BG", "BG", 
                                                                         "BG", "BG", "BG", "BG"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                     3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Baseline", 
                                                                                                                                                                                     "Post-intervention", "3-month follow-up"), class = "factor"), 
                     result = c(1.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 
                               0.9, 0.5, 1, 0.6, 0.2, 3.3, 0.2, 0.2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case_when` expects the arguments to have same length.  If we do subset, it may trigger  a reaction because one of the component become mismatched in length.  One option after grouping by 'id' would be to substract the 'result' from the case where 'time' is "Baseline" (to take care of case where there are multiple "Baseline" duplicates, take the first element), subtract and do the comparison

```
library(dplyr)
ds %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(improvement = case_when(result - result[time == "Baseline"][1] <= 0.5 ~ 1, 
           TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```